# How to ignore case when using switch statements

Tags: java, switch-statement, case-insensitive

I'm using the switch statement and was wondering how to ignore cases when using the switch statement.

Answer (score 5):

You could convert the string you're checking to lowercase and switch on that:

```java
switch (myString.toLowerCase()) {
    case "something":
        doSomething();
        break;
    case "something else":
        doSomethingElse();
        break;
    default:
        etc();
}
```

Comment: Does that ignore the cases? It looks like it takes lower case. I'm trying to let it ignore whether the case is lower or upper case.

Comment: @RiverYoo by converting the string to lower case and then testing it against lower case strings, you're actually ignoring the case the original string had.

Comment: @Mureinik this is assuming every case value is in lower case, no? If "something" and "something else" are in mixed cases, and come from variables, this wouldn't apply. You'd have to make everything lower case.

Comment: @HugoM.Zuleta yup. The idea here is to force both the string you're switching on and the case values to lower case.

Comment: Be aware this doesn't always work.  Consider the Greek 'sigma', which has two lower-case forms.U+03C2 and U+03C3, and only one upper-case. The correct choice is context-dependent, which 'convert to lower' may not recognize.  Conversion to upper-case has similar problems elsewhere.